# Added SQL Server 2008 R2 to domain, can't send email

Tags: email, domain, sql-server-2008-r2, managed-service-accounts

I had a standalone machine running SQL Server 2008 R2 that I joined to a domain. I set up an MSA and set all of the SQL services to log in under it.
I can access the DB remotely and run queries, but database mail doesn't work. I created a user in MSDB for the MSA account and added it
to the DatabaseMailUserRole role. I get the following error when I send a test email:

## 1) Exception Information

Exception Type: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Common.BaseException 
Message: Mail configuration information could not be read from the database. 
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal 
TargetSite: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Objects.Account GetAccount(Int32) 
HelpLink: NULL Source: DatabaseMailEngine

## StackTrace Information

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.DataAccessAdapter.GetAccount(Int32 accountID) 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.CommandFactory.CreateSendMailCommand(DBSession dbSession) 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.CommandFactory.CreateCommand(DBSession dbSession) 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.Controller.CommandRunner.Run(DBSession db) 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.IMailProcess.ThreadCallBack.MailOperation(Object o)

## 2) Exception Information

Exception Type: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException 
Errors: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection 
Class: 16 
LineNumber: 1 
Number: 15247 
Procedure: sp_PostAgentInfo 
Server: CCPC\GRDB 
State: 1 
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider 
ErrorCode: -2146232060 
Message: User does not have permission to perform this action. 
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal 
TargetSite: Void OnError(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, Boolean) 
HelpLink: NULL

## StackTrace Information

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) 
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() 
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlIMail.Server.DataAccess.DataAccessAdapter.GetAccount(Int32 accountID)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it after much searching and trial and error.

1) Find the Binn directory for the instance and give the MSA user execute permission.
2) exec sp_addsrvrolemember 'MSA ', 'SysAdmin'

No idea why this last step is necessary or if it's even safe, but it works now.